# how to create multi auth in one single login form

Tags: laravel

I want to create an authentication system (one single form) that gives the ability to admin and student to access tow different interfaces the admin can access the control panel and the user access the main system. in addition, I want separate tables in the database one for the admin and the other for the student. is there a possible way to do this? any suggestions please and how to do it.

Thank you...

Comment: I am using laravel version 5.7

Comment: In the access controle you can use `laravel policies`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change redirectifauthenticated.php file in middleware folder.

I can edit my answer later, i can't access my codes right now. But this idea will work:

In the handle function:

```
          switch ($guard){
          case 'admin':
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()){
//if you are using some role package, use with auth()->user()->hasrole('admin'), depends //your package
              return redirect()->route('adminurl');
            }
            break;
          default:
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()){
                return redirect('/homepage');
            }
            break;
        }
        return $next($request);
```

In config/auth.php also you need to add admin guard to the guards section. Also same thing for providers.

this for providers:

```
       'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\AdminModel::class,
        ],
        ]
```

Comment: Thank you brother, provide me with your code if you can access your code

Comment: can you please show me your code I have Some issues.